# how to give one column gap between each item component using Material-ui Grid?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, css-grid

I am pretty new to Material UI for React,
As per design, i need to give One column gap between each item component (totaling 12 columns)

Ex. 3 Column item  + 1 column Gap + 3 Column item  + 1 column Gap + 3 Column item  + 1 column Gap

How to achieve this using xs/lg etc without creating empty column item OR margin padding as that would be static.

Answer (score 0):

You would need column offset, as with bootstrap grid, but it is [not supported](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/11251) by material-ui.
In my opinion, there is nothing wrong with adding an extra column, you could event wrap it in a component:

```
function MyColumn({ children, ...rest }) {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Grid item {...rest}>
        {children}
      </Grid>
      <Grid item xs={1} />
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit ancient-leaf-josd6]

Comment: the problem with this approach is mobile xs view, where it gets converted to xs=12, there i want to handle spacings in a different way i.e margin top & bottom.

Comment: If you want to style your component differently depending on the viewport width, Material-UI provides a convenient utility component called Hidden: https://material-ui.com/components/hidden/